# RuntimeError: shape '[4, 3]' is invalid for input of size 3

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, touch

I tried to compute the Euler angles from the quaternion using this code:

```
def compute_euler_angles_from_quaternion(quaternions, sequence='xyz'):
   
    batch_size = quaternions.shape[0]
    print("Batch size:", batch_size)        
    q = quaternions.detach().cpu().numpy()  # Convert to NumPy array  
    
    rotations = Rotation.from_quat(q)
    print("q shape & type :", q.shape, type(q))
    print("q :", q)
    euler_angles = rotations.as_euler(sequence, degrees=False)
    print("Shape of euler_angles:", euler_angles.shape, euler_angles)
    euler_angles = torch.tensor(euler_angles, device=quaternions.device)
    euler_angles = euler_angles.view(batch_size, 3)

    return euler_angles
```

But I got this issue when the batch sizes == 1 or 2, or 16:

```
......

Batch size: 2
    q shape & type : (2, 4) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    q : [[-0.02834811  0.38461712 -0.17447884  0.9059931 ]
     [-0.08619151  0.40973052  0.17108667  0.8918639 ]]
    Shape of euler_angles: (2, 3) [[-0.25826138  0.75739155 -0.48375319]
     [-0.02085263  0.86383674  0.3694439 ]]
    Batch size: 2
    q shape & type : (2, 4) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    q : [[-8.2189016e-02 -1.8607294e-04  3.9553974e-02  9.9583155e-01]
     [-1.4399211e-01  5.9701569e-02  3.8889091e-02  9.8701048e-01]]
    Shape of euler_angles: (2, 3) [[-0.16445085  0.00613125  0.07889206]
     [-0.285834    0.12941251  0.06011334]]
    Batch size: 4
    q shape & type : (4,) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    q : [-0.07577483  0.17546612 -0.10769336  0.9756393 ]
    Shape of euler_angles: (3,) [-0.19766829  0.3321353  -0.25311127]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test_quat.py", line 147, in <module>
        euler = utils.compute_euler_angles_from_quaternion(
      File "/home/redhwan/2/HPE/quat/utils.py", line 304, in compute_euler_angles_from_quaternion
        euler_angles = euler_angles.view(batch_size, 3)
    RuntimeError: shape '[4, 3]' is invalid for input of size 3
```

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not very  familiar with quanternions, but what exactly is ```quaternions[0]``` type?

Comment: My guess is the problem lies in `quaternions.detach` or `quaternions` itself.  For batch size 4, following the `2` case I'd expect a (4,4) shape for `q`.  `q` instead is a 1d (4,) shape.

Comment: @hpaulj ,I replaced  q = quaternions.detach().cpu().numpy()   by q = quaternions.cpu().numpy(). The same issue.